# Brake Job 1998 Ford Ranger XLTV6 - 4.0L vin X 245ci

Tags: ford, brakes, ranger

A buddy of mine went to back up one day in his Ranger and his rear left tire was leaking brake fluid heavily. We parked it, jacked it up, removed the wheel, and discovered the wheel cylinder was so heavily corroded it had basically just fallen apart.

The shoes and springs were all in similar condition, so I went ahead and purchased all new shoes, the spring kit, and pads for the front disks, as well as new bolts and pins for the calipers, new bolts for the brake lines, and new bleeders (the front calipers bleeder valves needed a desk mounted clamp to unscrew).

After replacing everything I bled the brakes, starting with the back right tire and moving my way closer to the master cylinder from furthest line to shortest and everything worked fine.

I went to start the car and the pressure was immediately lost. I'm not very sure why this has happened and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: the car cannot go into P. The shift linkage is broken, and makes it impossible to access 1st and P. So it's in N with the parking brake off when I bleed it.

Comment: keep bleeding...

Comment: Make sure to keep filling the fluid reservoir as you bleed. Otherwise you will be fighting an unending battle.

Comment: You may have to bleed the master cylinder. Which is annoying by hand, worth picking up a $10 vacuum bleeder at Horrible Freight. Also make sure that the rear brake shoes are actually making contact with the drums.

Comment: When the car is in N and I have the back wheels off and I'm looking at the drum should the axlel be able to freely rotate ? Or should it be firm and hard to rotate and also hard to get the drum off?

Comment: I thought the 'classic' drum adjustment was to take it until it locks then back it off 2 clicks.  The 'pressure lost' when starting the car is due to the vacuum assist.  it just makes the pedal easier to press.  You can do a search on my posts for different bleeding methods.

Answer (score 1):

Did you adjust the rear brake shoes?  (I assume drum brakes), if not, there is a large gap that has to be made up before the brakes work.

Make sure you have the adjuster installed correctly.

Did you bleed with a person pumping the brakes or with one of the tools available?  If tools, pump the brakes and the pressure should come back (assuming you filled the master cylinder so it never sucked air).